# Dynamic tooltip for Dynamic Highchart

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I am making dynamic highchart (SPline updating every second).
I need to pass the dynamic tooltip for the graph.
For my actual code i get data from CSV.

I have update my sample code here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b2yj2L14/1/).

I have given tooltip : `'tooltip text <br>'` in this sample code.
This works only for the first 20 records.
Then the rest shows as undefined.

I have to pass the tooltip in the ajax call as well.
I tried like this :

```
 t='my tooltip';
 series.addPoint([x, y,t], true, true);
```

But it shows undefined.

Can any one help me to show the tooltip.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
series.addPoint([x, y,t], true, true);
```

This does not work. When passing an array it will just use the `x` and `y` value and discard the `t`. Instead you need to pass an object to provide the `t` variable.

For example:

```
series.addPoint({x:x, y:y, t:t}, true, true);
```

This is the same as you are doing when setting your `data` array in the options, using `data.push` inside your function.

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2yj2L14/2/) of how it works.